# Soap call works in soap ui but does not work in php - issue is, embedding keystore.jks

Tags: php, xml, web-services, wsdl, soapui

The problem we are encountering is that we can make a successful soap call with soapui but can not make the same call utilizing PHP.

Please find below the header we are using in soap ui.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:hubc="http://hubc.ee.sim.dsh.cms.hhs.gov" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-464FFDDFED6BF260B214424061128904">
            <wsu:Created>2015-09-16T12:21:52.890Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2015-09-16T12:22:52.890Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-464FFDDFED6BF260B214424061097963">
            <wsse:Username>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">8pmfYIJhqvkRLIcrR/R2yOoEelg=</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">xxxxxxxxxxxxx</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2015-09-16T12:21:49.796Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <hubc:HubConnectivityRequest/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Soap ui has a GUI interface that allows us to place a keystore file in to the soap call. We do not know how that keystore is embedded into the soap call.

Any advice as to how to make the keystore function in php the same way as it does in soap ui would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Can you post the logs for the error in PHP? Also, can you confirm that you are using HTTPS for the SOAP service?

Comment: yes I can confirm that we are using HTTPS for the SOAP service

Comment: did you find its solution in php , I am stuck in this for a long time. If you have found one please share with me, this is healthcare.gov hubconnectivity  webservice right

Answer (score 0):

Wed Sep 16 16:03:21 EDT 2015:DEBUG:>> "POST /HubConnectivityService HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
Wed Sep 16 16:03:21 EDT 2015:DEBUG:>> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
Wed Sep 16 16:03:21 EDT 2015:DEBUG:>> "Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="